I got Column error each time i change model.py
When i want to change or add one more model in Models.py , i got this error :
OperationalError at /admin/groups/group/
no such column: groups_group.کد

it only happens when it is the second time that im going to change the model. for the first time it doesnt have any special error.
i run this commands but it doesnt help me :
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate

and also :
python manage.py makemigrations appname
python manage.py migrate appname

here is my code :
Models.py:
from django.db import models

class Group(models.Model):
    کد = models.IntegerField(max_length = 5, default = 00000)
    عنوان = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    توضیحات_شماره_یک = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    توضیحات_شماره_دو = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    توضیحات_شماره_سه = models.CharField(max_length = 100)


Views.py:
from django.shortcuts import render


def groups(request):
    return render(request, "groups/groups.html")

def group(request):
    return render(request, "groups/group.html")


Urls.py:
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.groups, name = "groups"),
    path('group/', views.group, name = "group")
]

Admin.py:
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Group

admin.site.register(Group)



When i want to change or add one more model in Models.py , i got this error Do you mean add one field to the model?

Yes , for example I mean adding code = models.integerfield() or editing one of them

Delete all migration files except init.py and try makemigrations, migrate again

@user16171413 please don't advise people to delete migrations without understanding their problems. We already have enough incorrect guidance on the site as it is.

I've closed this as a duplicate for now. If the error happens when running makemigrations and migrate then please [edit] and add in the complete error traceback. Also provide a [mre].
